# JavaScript transform flat array to nested / grouped and sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, transform

I am trying to transform an array of objects to a **'grouped' and sorted output array** in JavaScript, preferably the ES6-way (e.g. using `.map`, `.reduce`, etc.).

Summary:

- array of objects
- each object is an 'item': a1,a2,b1,b2,...
- each object has a 'section' property which is like a group/category
- the desired output array should return the item objects grouped by 'section'
- the sorting order of the output arrays of sections and items is defined in a property as well

```
const data = [
    { section: 'A', item: 'a1', section_order: 2, item_order: 2 },
    { section: 'B', item: 'b1', section_order: 1, item_order: 2 },
    { section: 'A', item: 'a2', section_order: 2, item_order: 1 },
    { section: 'B', item: 'b2', section_order: 1, item_order: 1 }
];


const desiredOutput = [
    {
        section: 'B',  // should come first as section_order = 1
        items: [
            { section: 'B', item: 'b2', section_order: 1, item_order: 1 },  // should come first as item_order = 1
            { section: 'B', item: 'b1', section_order: 1, item_order: 2 },   // should come second as item_order = 2
        ]
    },
    {
        section: 'A',   // should come second as section_order = 2
        items: [
            { section: 'A', item: 'a2', section_order: 2, item_order: 1 },
            { section: 'A', item: 'a1', section_order: 2, item_order: 2 },
        ]
    }
];
```

I saw an example that gets me somewhere in the right direction - but not exactly to the desired output and without catering for the sorting-order:

```
const result = data.reduce((accum, currElm) => {
    const currSection = currElm['section'];
    accum[currSection] = (accum[currSection] || []).concat(currElm);
    return accum;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `sort` your data first. The `sort` function look like this

```
data.sort((a, b) => (a.section_order - b.section_order) || (a.item_order - b.item_order));
```

As you can see, we split the condition into 2 parts:

1. `(a.section_order - b.section_order)`
2. `(a.item_order - b.item_order)`

It means that you sort `section_order` then by `item_order`.

After that, you can loop just one time by using *dictionary power* like below

```js
const data = [
    { section: 'A', item: 'a1', section_order: 2, item_order: 2 },
    { section: 'B', item: 'b1', section_order: 1, item_order: 2 },
    { section: 'A', item: 'a2', section_order: 2, item_order: 1 },
    { section: 'B', item: 'b2', section_order: 1, item_order: 1 }
];
data.sort((a, b) => (a.section_order - b.section_order) || (a.item_order - b.item_order));

var result = [];
for(var item of data){
  var section = item.section;
  if(!result[section]){ // if not exists => create new 
    result[section] = { section, items:[item] };
  }else{ // if exists => add one more item into items 
   result[section].items.push(item);
  }
}
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

**Old version using `reduce & map`**

```js
const data = [
    { section: 'A', item: 'a1', section_order: 2, item_order: 2 },
    { section: 'B', item: 'b1', section_order: 1, item_order: 2 },
    { section: 'A', item: 'a2', section_order: 2, item_order: 1 },
    { section: 'B', item: 'b2', section_order: 1, item_order: 1 }
];
data.sort((a, b) => (a.section_order - b.section_order) || (a.item_order - b.item_order));

const accumData = data.reduce((accum, currElm) => {
    const currSection = currElm['section'];
    accum[currSection] = (accum[currSection] || []).concat(currElm);
    return accum;
}, {}); 


var result = Object.entries(accumData).map(([key, value]) => ({section: key, items: value}));
console.log(result);
```